# Is there a way to quickly allocate a large chunk of memory filled with 0xFF?

Tags: c, optimization, operating-system, mmap, virtual-memory

I need to allocate a large (lets say, 1gb) chunk of memory, and initialize every byte to 0xFF.

From some searching, it sounds like one can use `mmap` and `MAP_PRIVATE` to do something like this, but I can't wrap my head around how that could be possible, with the `mmap` parameters.

Any idea how we can do this with `mmap`, or with any other mechanism, in a performant way? Thanks!

Comment: The [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) on `mmap` is helpful for explaining all the flags. I believe the correct way to allocate a GB with `mmap` would be `mmap(NULL, 1073741824, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0)`. At least I *think* that's the amount of bytes that make up a GB. As for setting all to 0xFF, `memset` might be the best option. Make sure to check if `mmap` returns `NULL` though.